# Using a variable in a Perl 6 program before assigning to it

Tags: raku

I want to assign literals to some of the variables at the end of the file with my program, but to use these variables earlier. The only method I've come up with to do it is the following:

```perl6
my $text;

say $text;

BEGIN {    
    $text = "abc";
}
```

Is there a better / more idiomatic way?

Comment: Why do you want to write your logic backwards?

Comment: Explaining why you want to define them at the end instead of at the top would make your question much more interesting and also give us ideas as to what would be better or more idiomatic for your situation.

Comment: For example, do you want to effectively have an embedded configuration file at the end? And if so, why would you prefer that over a regular configuration file, etc.

Comment: @melpomene E.g. I sometimes need to have several multi-line constants (either strings or regexes), and it's very inconvenient to have them at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky I think your solution is a reasonable one for constants. If you're defining run-time values, you could use much the same approach but use the [`INIT` phaser](https://docs.perl6.org/language/phasers#index-entry-Phasers__INIT-INIT) instead of `BEGIN`.

Comment: @raiph Thanks! They are mostly not runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just go functional.

Create subroutines instead:

```
say text();

sub text { "abc" }
```

---

---

UPDATE (Thanks raiph! Incorporating your feedback, including reference to using [`term:<>`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/term:%3C%3E)):

In the above code, I originally omitted the parentheses for the call to `text`, but it would be more maintainable to always include them to prevent the parser misunderstanding our intent. For example,

```
say text();          # "abc" 
say text() ~ text(); # "abcabc"
say text;            # "abc", interpreted as: say text()
say text ~ text;     # ERROR, interpreted as: say text(~text())

sub text { "abc" };
```

To avoid this, you could make `text` a [term](https://docs.raku.org/routine/term:%3C%3E), which effectively makes the bareword `text` behave the same as `text()`:

```
say text;        # "abc",    interpreted as: say text() 
say text ~ text; # "abcabc", interpreted as: say text() ~ text()

sub term:<text> { "abc" };
```

For compile-time optimizations and warnings, we can also add the [`pure` trait](https://docs.raku.org/routine/is%20pure) to it (thanks Brad Gilbert!). `is pure` asserts that for a given input, the function ["always produces the same output without any additional side effects"](https://docs.raku.org/routine/is%20pure):

```
say text;        # "abc",    interpreted as: say text() 
say text ~ text; # "abcabc", interpreted as: say text() ~ text()

sub term:<text> is pure { "abc" };
```

Comment: Note that the identifier Christopher declares (`text`) is declared as an ordinary `sub`. So, for example, if you wrote, `say text ~ text` you wouldn't get `abcabc` displayed but would instead get a run-time error `Too many positionals passed; expected 0 arguments but got 1` because the first `text` would be a `sub` that's passed `~ text` as an argument.

Comment: (Further to my prior comment, cf [`term:<>`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/term:%3C%3E#%28Syntax%29_term_term:%3C%3E), especially the `dice` example.)

Comment: @raiph Thanks! Updated to include your suggestions (pointing out the potential problem of omitting the parentheses and the suggested use of [term:<>](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/term:%3C%3E) instead).

Comment: You probably want to add `is pure` to the `term:<text>` so that compile-time optimizations and errors can happen.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Perl 5, in Perl 6 a `BEGIN` does not have to be a block.  However, the lexical definition must be seen before it can be used, so the `BEGIN` block must be done before the `say`.

```
BEGIN my $text = "abc";
say $text;
```

Not sure whether this constitutes an answer to your question or not.

Comment: His code works in v6 with Rakudo Star 2018.01. That might not be "correct", but it works.

Comment: I agree the code is correct.  And will continue to be correct.  I merely wanted to point out a different, more idiomatic way, as the question was.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Thanks, I didn't know that `BEGIN` doesn't need a block.

Comment: FWIW, this applies to *all* phasers!

Answer (score 3):

First, a rephrase of your question:

> What options are there for succinctly referring to a variable (or constant etc.) whose initialization code appears further down in the same source file?

## Post declare a routine

```
say foo;
sub foo { 'abc' }
```

When a P6 compiler parses an [identifier](https://docs.perl6.org/language/syntax#Identifiers) that has *no [sigil](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#index-entry-Sigil)*, it checks to see if it has already seen a declaration of that identifier. If it hasn't, then it assumes that the identifier corresponds to a routine which will be declared later as a "listop" routine (which takes zero or more arguments) and moves on. (If its assumption turns out to be wrong, it fails the compilation.)

So you can use routines as if they were variables as described in [Christopher Bottom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49176478/1077672).

## Autodeclare a variable on first use

[strict](https://docs.perl6.org/language/pragmas#index-entry-strict-strict) is a ["pragma"](https://docs.perl6.org/language/pragmas) that controls how a P6 compiler reacts when it parses an as yet undeclared variable/constant that starts with a [sigil](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#index-entry-Sigil).

P6 starts programs with strict mode switched on. This means that the compiler will insist on predeclaration of any sigil'd variable/constant. (By predeclaration I mean an *explicit* declaration that appears *textually* before the variable/constant is used.)

But you can write `use strict` or `no strict` to control whether the strict pragma is on or off in a given lexical scope, so this will work:

```
no strict;

say $text;

BEGIN {    
    $text = "abc";
}
```

**Warning** Having `no strict` in effect (which is unfortunately how most programming languages work) makes accidental misspelling of variable names a bigger nuisance than it is with `use strict` mode on.

## Declare a variable explicitly in the same statement as its first use

You don't have to write a declaration as a separate statement. You can instead declare *and* use a variable in the same statement or expression:

```
say my $text;

BEGIN {    
    $text = "abc";
}
```

**Warning** If you repeat `my $bar` in the *exact same* lexical scope, the compiler will emit a warning. In contrast, `say my $bar = 42; if foo { say my $bar = 99 }` creates two distinct `$bar` variables without warning.

## Initialize at run-time

The `BEGIN` phaser shown above runs at *compile*-time (after the `my` declaration, which also happens at compile-time, but before the `say`, which happens at run-time).

If you want to initialize variables/constants at run-time instead, use [`INIT`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/phasers#INIT) instead:

```
say my $text;

INIT {    
    $text = "abc";
}
```

`INIT` code runs before any other run-time code, so the initialization still happens before the `say` gets executed.

## Use a positronic (`ym`) variable

Given a literal interpretation of your question a "positronic" or `ym` variable would be yet another solution. (This feature is not built-in. I'm including it mostly because I encountered it after answering this question and think it belongs here, at the very least for entertainment value.)

Initialization and calculation of such a variable starts in the *last* statement using it and occurs backwards relative to the textual order of the code.

This is one of the several crazy sounding but actually working and useful concepts that Damian "mad scientist" Conway discusses in his 2011 presentation *Temporally Quaquaversal Virtual Nanomachine Programming In Multiple Topologically Connected Quantum-Relativistic Parallel Spacetimes... Made Easy!*.

Here's a link to [the bit where he focuses on these variables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORjyXcLDd9M&index=33&t=40m20s&list=PLRuESFRW2Fa77XObvk7-BYVFwobZHdXdK).

(The whole presentation is a delight, especially if you're interested in physics; programming techniques; watching highly creative wunderkinds; and/or enjoy outstanding presentation skills and humor.)

## Create a `PS` pragma?

In terms of coolness, the following pales in comparison to Damian's positronic variable feature that I just covered, but it's an idea I had while pondering this question.

Someone could presumably implement something like the following pragma:

```
use PS;

say $text;

BEGIN $text = 'abc';
```

This `PS` would lexically apply `no strict` and in addition require that, to avoid a compile-time error:

- An auto-declared variable/constant must match up with a post declaration in a `BEGIN` or `INIT` phaser;
- The declaration must include initialization if the first use (textually) of a variable/constant is not a binding or assignment.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful explanations, now I know all the options.